# sound lost in auxiliar speakers any time there is an update

Tags: pulseaudio

every update in ubuntu 22.10 gets reed of the sound in the auxiliar speakers out. To restart the sound I have to do:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
```

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

This change is reverted after an update, and the sound is **gone**.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 22.10?   1 (one) and 10 (ten) are different numbers; and Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format but no release occurred in 2022-January (22.01).  Do you mean 22.10 or are you not using Ubuntu?